# Google Apps Script: Problem with error "Exception: Couldn't open document ... Unable to load document."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I keep getting the following error message when I run my code:
"Exception: Couldn't open document with id 1IOwbcFWrh_jEeZbhVgw5fEbGOtM6zXKpmdrO_qUGNZM: Unable to load document."
I can't see any reason why this error message appears. I'm pretty sure the code is correct, I'm only using one Google account and the ID of the document is also correct (it's the same as in the link to the document). I have no other Google documents open and I'm the owner of the document and the script. So the permissions should not be a problem either.

Since I can't find any other posts about this particular error, I'm hoping someone here has an idea of what I'm missing.

```
function deleteFirstRow() {
// Die Tabelle öffnen.
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

// Delete first row
var rrange = activeSheet.getRange("1:1");
rrange.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}
```

Ausführungsprotokoll
13:29:32    Hinweis Ausführung begonnen
13:30:45    Fehler
Exception: Couldn't open document with id 1IOwbcFWrh_jEeZbhVgw5fEbGOtM6zXKpmdrO_qUGNZM: Unable to load document.
deleteFirstRow  @ Code.gs:9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRvA1.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your function works fine when I run it in a spreadsheet of my own.  A few clarifications: 1. Is your script [container-bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to a spreadsheet?  2. Is there any other code in your project or just this snippet? 3. How are you running this function (e.g. from the code editor, from a custom menu or button in the spreadsheet, from a trigger)?